# How to make TypeScript string enums that work with string literals and do type inference correctly

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I want a type to describe a set of strings, and an object with keys for easy access to said strings.

## Option 1 (doesn't provide proper type inferencing)

When `const TwoWords` is initialized with all of the keys' values type-asserted to TwoWords, then `DoSomething(TwoWords.Foo)` compiles, but the typeguard on the switch statement doesn't work as expected - the type of `word` in the default case is not `never`.

```
type TwoWords = 'foo' | 'bar';
const TwoWords = {
    Foo: 'foo' as TwoWords,
    Bar: 'bar' as TwoWords
};

function DoSomething(word: TwoWords) {
    switch (word) {
        case TwoWords.Foo:
            break;
        case TwoWords.Bar:
            break;
        default:
            let typeInferenceCheck: never = word; // Type '"foo"' is not assignable to type 'never'
    }
}

DoSomething(TwoWords.Foo);
DoSomething('bar');
```

## Option 2 (correct type inference, but overly verbose)

However, if I use a string literal type assertion for each of `TwoWords` keys' values, the type of `word` in the default case is `never` as I would expect.

```
type TwoWords = 'foo' | 'bar';
const TwoWords = {
    Foo: 'foo' as 'foo',
    Bar: 'bar' as 'bar'
};

function DoSomething(word: TwoWords) {
    switch (word) {
        case TwoWords.Foo:
            break;
        case TwoWords.Bar:
            break;
        default:
            let typeInferenceCheck: never = word; // OK
    }
}

DoSomething(TwoWords.Foo);
DoSomething('bar');
```

In cases where `'foo'` and `'bar'` are much longer strings (say, a whole sentence), I don't want to duplicate them - it's too verbose. Is there another way to have a string keyed enum that behaves as expected from a type-inference perspective in a switch statement (or if/else chain)?

## Option 3 (not interchangeable with string literals)

As per Madara Uchiha's answer, you can get proper type inference (as in Option 2) without the verbosity using TypeScript 2.4 string enums, but these aren't interchangeable with string literals.

```
DoSomething('bar'); // Type '"bar"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TwoWords'
```

(See [GitHub issue #15930 about string literal assignment to TypeScript 2.4 string enum](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15930))

## Criteria

I am looking for another option which allows me to have:

1. An **enum-style object** for accessing string literals `EnumLikeObject.Foo === 'foo'`
2. A **type** indicating that only enum members are allowed, whether they are:

   1. string literals - `let thing: EnumLikeObject = 'foo'`
   2. properties of the enum-style object - `let thing: EnumLikeObject = EnumLikeObject.Foo`
3. the enum-style object and the type must have the **same name**
4. In the declaration of the enum-style object and the type, no string literal may be repeated more than twice. If you've got a solution where they must only be repeated once, even better. (In this question, when I speak of verbosity, this criteria is primarily what I'm referring to.)

**Objections & Discussion**

- [issue #15930 link from Option 3 about string enums and string literals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15930) says "The rational here is if you use string enums, you should use them all the way to ensure safe refactoring, otherwise stick with literal types"

  - In our project, we use a parsing library for some xml data (we don't control the data format). This gives us a typed object that uses string literal types, which we map to our internally used objects which use these string enums. (Hence the requirement about string literals.) Sometimes, we work the other way from internal object to generating xml, and for ease of use in those cases we want an enum not just literal types.
  - I may look into changing the type definition for that parsing library to use our string enums instead of literals and then I can drop the string literal assignment requirement, but I'd rather avoid that because that library isn't our responsibility and it seems rather hacky to use our internal types from an external library.
- [issue #16389 from @tycho's comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16389) says that "any literal that is not a constant is predicted to change in value, though not in type" which is why you need to tell the compiler if you know that a variable actually won't change in type beyond certain bounds. The compiler must infer the most general type to allow for changes in the value.

Comment: This seems to come down to the ability to get `'foo'` inference without having to write `'foo' as 'foo'`. This seems the topic of [#16389](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16389).

Comment: Thanks for the link @Tycho. Yes, if the type of `foo` was inferred as `'foo'` and not `string`, that would make my "option 2" less verbose and solve the problem. As explained in that linked GitHub issue, it's an issue of mutability. `const foo = 'foo';` does have a type of `'foo'`, whereas `let foo = 'foo'` has a type of `string`; Not sure how to leverage that to solve this though. Any ideas?

Comment: Hah, I didn't even know that already worked if you're storing the strings with `const`! So I guess that means what's left is for them to extend that behavior to objects (and arrays). Until then, what if you say `const Foo = 'foo'; const Bar = 'bar'; const TwoWords = { Foo, Bar };`? Still not perfect but yeah.

Comment: Surprisingly, that also doesn't work (just tried it). Property `Foo` has type `'foo'`, but then `TwoWords` has type `{ Foo: string, Bar: string }`.

Comment: Ouch... maybe subscribe to that issue hoping they'll consider supporting this at one point. I'll fav here too in the event someone comes up with a miracle for the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got it. At least:

- I'm not seeing any red underlines in my code.
- `DoSomething` accepts either `"foo"` or `"bar"`.
- In the default case, word is void.

And to satisfy your criteria

1. `TwoWords.Foo === 'foo'`
2. The type only allows the literal values specified.
3. the enum-style object and the type have the same name
4. The string literals are only written once

And so without further ado:

```
const TwoWords = (function () {
    const Foo = 'foo';
    const Bar = 'bar';

    const ret = {
        Foo: Foo as typeof Foo,
        Bar: Bar as typeof Bar,
    };
    return ret;
})()
type TwoWords = typeof TwoWords[keyof typeof TwoWords];
```

And then I had a light bulb moment

```
namespace TwoWords2 {
    export const Foo = "foo";
    export const Bar = "bar";
}
type TwoWords2 = typeof TwoWords2[keyof typeof TwoWords2]
// didn't test this, not sure if it actually updates the 
// original object or just returns a frozen copy
Object.freeze(TwoWords2);
```

It's not a downside, in my opinion, because it still throws an error in the type checker and in VS Code, but `TwoWords2.Bar = "five"` actually works because the namespace gets compiled to a simple object. But that's the way typescript works. Obviously the first code also has that problem, but it wouldn't throw a type error, so the second is superior, IMO.

Comment: That's beautiful

Comment: It looks like `let thing = TwoWords.Bar; DoSomething(thing);` doesn't work with this solution, but it does with "option 2" from my question - but I don't think there's any way to get around that. `let thing = 'bar'; DoSomething(thing);` also doesn't work as per issue #16389

Comment: Honestly, you shouldn't be assigning a literal type to a let variable. What happens if you change it later? You'll end up with `"foo" as "bar"`!

If you use const it will carry over the way you want it to. `const thing = TwoWords.Bar; DoSomething(thing);`

Comment: If you literally want to do that, then you have to tell typescript that's what you want: `let me: typeof TwoWords2.Bar = TwoWords2.Bar;`. But I don't recommend it because you'll risk breaking your type checking, and `const` works perfectly fine.

Comment: That's a good point - though in my case it's actually `let someObject = { /* etc */ thing: TwoWords.Bar }` - so making it const doesn't fix it, and neither would `const thing = TwoWords.Bar; let someObject = { thing };`.

Comment: By the way I've got 3 hours before I can award the bounty but then it's yours

Comment: Ok, no problem :). This works for me: `{ thing: thing as typeof thing }`.

Comment: And `{ thing: thing as TwoWords2 }` and of course `{ thing: TwoWords2.Bar as TwoWords2 }`. You got the idea :)

Comment: Yes, exactly. And that's what they say in issue #16389 - if you know that it's something more specific than just a string, you'll need to explicitly tell the compiler. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 6):

<s>If you care to wait and endure for a bit,</s>

[TypeScript 2.4](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2017/06/12/announcing-typescript-2-4-rc/) brings true string enums to the playing field:

```
enum TwoWords {
  Foo = 'foo',
  Bar = 'bar'
}

function DoSomething(word: TwoWords) {
    switch (word) {
        case TwoWords.Foo:
            break;
        case TwoWords.Bar:
            break;
        default:
            let typeCheck: never = word; // OK
    }
}
```

That gets you the best of both worlds.

Comment: That's awesome! Yes, I can update to 2.4 and that works -- almost. It's not actually enough though, because I need to be able to assign string literals to variables typed with this string keyed enum. I did mention that in point 2 of my requirements, but I can see how it wasn't entirely clear. I updated the examples to include `DoSomething('bar')` which doesn't work with TypeScript 2.4 string keyed enums. Any suggestions?

Comment: Huh, that actually seems like a bug in TypeScript, I'd expect it to work...

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems to be [by design and not a bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15930).